# Was ist der im Deutschen verwendete Fachbegriff für "Beiname"?

Tags: etymology, single-word-request, scientific-language

Mich quält seit Jahren der Gedanke, einen bestimmten Fachbegriff der Sprachwissenschaft vergessen zu haben. Nämlich handelt es sich dabei um einen Fachbegriff, der in etwa die Bedeutung "Beiname" haben soll. Ich weiß nur noch, dass der „schnelle Achilles“ das definierende Beispiel sein sollte; also mit einem Namen oft verwendete Adjektive/Beschreibungen, die allmählich Teil des Namens wurden.

Ich dachte der Begriff wäre "Epinym", doch dieses Wort gibt es nicht, oder hat andere Bedeutung (siehe Eponym).

Comment: Ja stimmt. Wurde editiert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Epitheton

Zitat [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitheton):

> Insbesondere wurde dieser Begriff des schmückenden Epithetons von den klassischen Philologen gebraucht, um die seit Homer in der epischen bzw. episierenden Sprache zahlreich vorkommenden konventionellen Attribute bei Götter- und Heldennamen, aber auch bei gewöhnlichen Gegenständen zu bezeichnen, so: „die kuhäugige Hera“, „die rosenfingrige Eos“, „der listenreiche Odysseus“, „die wolletragenden Schafe“.

> Diejenigen epischen Epitheta, die „unabhängig von der jeweiligen Situation eine unveränderliche Eigenschaft vor allem von Personen bezeichnen“ – wie „pius Aeneas“ (Vergil, Aeneis 1,305) –, heißen auch Epitheton constans (‚feststehendes Beiwort‘).

Comment: Besten Dank, genau das ist der gesuchte Begriff!

Comment: Ah, jetzt weiß ich endlich, wie das heißt, was Trump immer für seine Gegner etablieren wollte ("crooked Hillary", "sleepy Joe", ...)